# Using limits to determine if $a_n=\frac{(\ln n)^2}{\sqrt{n}}$ (without L'Hospital) is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits-without-lhopital

$a_n=\frac{(\ln n)^2}{\sqrt{n}}$ $(n\ge1)$

Would I use the squeeze theorem or can I just take the limit of top and bottom?

using L'Hopital, I get  $a_n=\frac{(4\ln n)}{\sqrt{n}}$ $(n\ge1)$

Comment: A limit of top and bottom would be $\infty/\infty$.  You could use L'Hospital's rule.  There's probably a way to do it with the Squeeze theorem, but none that immediately come to mind.

Comment: Actually, you haven't asked a question yet. Also, $a_n \ne (4\ln n)/\sqrt n).$

Comment: That was after using L'hopitals

Comment: Once we have $\lim_{x\to \infty}(\ln x)/x =0$, we also have, for positive $a,b$,  that  $(\ln x)^a/x^b=$ $((\ln x)/x^{b/a})^a=$ $((a/b)(\ln x^{b/a})/x^{b/a})^a=$ $(a/b)^a\cdot ((\ln y)/y)^a, $ with $y=x^{b/a}. $  And since $y\to \infty$ as $x\to \infty,$ we obtain  $\lim_{x\to \infty} (\ln x)^a/x^b=0.$

Comment: zhw means you shoulnd't call both sequences the same, because they are diferent, try giving it another name different from $a_n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the expression as:

$$a_n = \left(\frac{4\,\log n^{\frac{1}{4}}}{n^{\frac{1}{4}}}\right)^2$$

and you should make headway, using the well known fact that $log\,u/u\to0$ as $u\to\infty$.

---

You're simply using the definition of a [continuous function in terms of limits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Definition_in_terms_of_limits_of_sequences) for the function $f(x)=x^2$. To prove $\mathscr{L}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\log n}{n}=0$ we make a substitution $n=e^u$ and then $\mathscr{L} = \lim\limits_{u\to\infty}\frac{u}{e^u}$. Since $e^u > 1 + u + \frac{u^2}{2!}$, this last one should be no problem.

Comment: So would this be a comparison test?

Comment: @anna_xox Are you seeking the limit $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ of the *series* sum  or the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n$? This answer addresses the latter; the comparison test is for series. The main fact used here is the function of the limit is the limit of the function for any cts function;  indeed this is one of several equivalent *definitions* of continuity.

Comment: I'm asking for a sequence so for the latter.

Comment: @anna_xox Then see further info at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

$$\ln{n}=4\ln{n^{\frac{1}{4}}}$$ and $$\sqrt{n}=(n^{\frac{1}{4}})^2$$ and you know $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln{x}}{x}=0$ thus $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}a_{n}=\frac{16(\ln{n^{1/4})^2}}{(n^{1/4})^2}=0$$

Comment: I have done some working above.

Comment: i did not get  you , i have not used l'hospital here

Comment: So I think you have done a substitution, and then used the comparison test?

Answer (score 2):

Squeeze theorem is sufficient (and nice) here. More generally we prove that if $a, b$ are positive real numbers then $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(\log n)^{a}}{n^{b}} = 0\tag{1}$$ Let $f(n) = (\log n)^{a}/n^{b}$ and $c = b/a$ and $g(n) = (\log n)/n^{c}$ so that $f(n) = \{g(n)\}^{a}$ and if we show that $g(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ then $f(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

We have $c > 0$ and hence it is possible to choose $d$ with $0 < d < c$. Let $n > 1$ so that $n^{d} > 1$ and then we know that $$0 < \log n^{d} < n^{d} - 1 < n^{d}$$ or $$0 < d \log n < n^{d}$$ or $$0 < \log n < \frac{n^{d}}{d}$$ and therefore $$0 < \frac{\log n}{n^{c}} < \frac{1}{dn^{d - c}}$$ Noting that $d - c > 0$ and applying Squeeze theorem when $n \to \infty$ we get $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\log n}{n^{c}} = 0\tag{2}$$ We have thus established that $g(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.